Packaging up a PyInfra deployment
After creating a deployment infrastructure with PyInfra, I need to share the PyInfra set-up with external people.
The sharing should happen as simply "Here is a zip file, extract it and run this command"
How can I package up PyInfra in to a single executable that will run and accept the correct information, from any (sub)system?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
